# Notifications in Android: change specific properties/fields?

Tags: android, notifications

On an Android 2.3.3 I want to update my Notification.

Today, I create a new Notification object, and fill it with stuff. That makes the ticker text show again, which I don't want. I just want to update the number in the Notification (and sometimes the contentText) without making a new Notification, and without replacing the current "contentText".

So:

1. How do I just update the number, without replacing any text (whatever text is in the notification now should be left untouched)
2. How do I get info on what text/data is in the current Notification?

Comment: And yes, you could save the Notification as a field in your Activity, but I am looking for a way to get the Notification from the system...

Answer (score 0):

Use custom notification and then update like this:

```
progressNotification.contentView.setProgressBar(R.id.PGB_UPLOAD, 100, percentage, false);

progressNotification.contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.TXV_UPLOAD_PROGRESS, String.valueOf(percentage)+"%");
objNotificationManager.notify(1, progressNotification);
```

Comment: Aha, well, that is one solution yes... I was more aiming for the standard things...

Answer (score 0):

You need to post the notification again, just as you said. To suppress the ticker, set the `tickerText` field to `null`.